# Angular:to check array length if 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple requirement i.e. if favorites array is empty hide the EDIT button.

Code i wrote on HTML:

```
    <span class="edit-button" *ngIf="favourites.length == 0">EDIT</span>
```

But I am getting an error on console `Unable to get property 'length' of undefined.`

I also tried `*ngIf="favourites?.length == 0"` still m getting the same error.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does the error shows where you are getting the error? A line number?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the initialization of property favourites in your component class.

Looks like the property is defined with no initialization, add the default value to it.

like below

```
 public favourites: Array<any> = [];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But he's using  **?** to check `favourites` undefined or not `*ngIf="favourites?.length == 0"`

Comment: That is not right syntax. could use. either `*ngIf="favourites ? favourites.length > 0 : false"` or `*ngIf="favourites && favourites.length > 0"` for this use case

Comment: you can use *ngIf="!favourites?.length"

Answer (score 0):

First you are checking if `favourites.length === 0` but your requirement says you need to hide if empty then it should be `favourites.length != 0` because `*ngIf` shows if its true.

You can check `favourites` first and then `favourites.length` which means it will first check for favourites initialization and if there is any data.

```
<span class="edit-button" *ngIf="favourites && favourites.length">EDIT</span>
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuzpx7

Answer (score 0):

To check length in angular

```
<div class="box stack-top" *ngIf="profile.id.length == 8"></div>
```